# Grey out (disable) a panel on webform (visual studio .aspx)

Tags: asp.net

Firstly, I am new to programming. I am currently having a website with 2 panel which are Log-in and Application Option. This is how I want it to work:
- When I first access the page, only the Log-in panel is editable while the Application Panel is grey out ( or disable)

- After I successfully logged in, the Log-in panel will be grey out ( or disable) while the Application Panel is now editable

Although I know how it works, however, coding is a bit of issue for me . Help and explaination will be really appreciated

Cheers

Comment: do you have any more details on the structure of the page, post the markup and codebehind sections

Comment: What authentication method do you use in your application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you are using asp.net web forms.

Also assuming both the panels are on the same page you can do something like this

in page_load

```
pnlApplication.Enabled = false;
pnlLogin.Enabled = true;
```

and in your login event or wherever you validate the user has actually logged in simply do the opposite

Comment: Thanks Daniel, the Login Panel works with code you provided, however the Application doesn't work like how I wanted it to since this Panel has few radio buttons, even when I set it to pnlApplication.Enabled= false, I could still select these radio button. Anyway to fix this ( only when before I log in )

Comment: disabling the panel should disable the controls within it, can you paste the code for the panel